# Telegram, Texting From Bot to Bot

Tags: php, telegram-bot

Is it possible to send message from a Telegram Bot to another Telegram Bot?

I got an error response when sending text to another bot either using @botname or directly botname as target id.

I'm sending a request by hitting url like this form `api.telegram.org/mybottoken/…` Im using .net to perform the operation.

The response is :

> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request) at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address) Sending text to human user is fine with the code, but not with the Bot.

Comment: Please share how you send the message AND the error message.

Comment: I'm sending a request by hitting url like this form

https://api.telegram.org/mybottoken/sendMessage?chat_id=otherbotusername&text=testmessage

Im using .net to perform the operation. The response is :
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address)



Sending text to human user is fine with the code, but not with the Bot.

Comment: No, it is not possible. A bot can only send messages to someone who has sent it messages. That means a bot can only talk to a human, but not another bot.

Comment: @NickLee thank you for the explanation. I've been trying to find this information, but I must have missed it on the documentation. Problem considered solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this as the answer to my question.

[@nick Lee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34918414/telegram-texting-from-bot-to-bot#comment57575844_34918414) :
No, it is not possible. A bot can only send messages to someone who has sent it messages. That means a bot can only talk to a human, but not another bot

From the documentation:

> #### [Why doesn't my bot see messages from other bots?](https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#why-doesn-39t-my-bot-see-messages-from-other-bots)
>
> Bots talking to each other could potentially get stuck in unwelcome loops. To avoid this, we decided that bots will not be able to see messages from other bots regardless of mode.